# Reducing the 1 milisecond latency after every 1024-bytes (micro)frame when reading stream with PyAudio

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi, usb, pyaudio

I have configured my SoC kit, which came with an integrated USB controller to act as a USB Audio 2.0 mono channel 8-bit PCM microphone with 48 KHz sampling frequency. It is set up with an asynchronous audio streaming interface over a single isochronous IN endpoint. I have connected it to a Raspberry Pi 3B+ and am using PyAudio to read the audio stream and store it as a WAV file.

For testing purposes, I am transmitting a sinusoidal signal stored in the SoC's RAM over the interface and has a period of 1024 samples. (Space occupied: 1024 bytes).

When the device endpoint is configured to support a polling period of 125 microseconds (Hence bInterval=1), the recorded WAV file shows blank periods after transmission of 1024 bytes, shown in the plot below.
[image: Mono-channel 8-bit PCM 0.5 second recording for Endpoint bInterval: 125 usec]

When zoomed in, it can be observed that their duration corresponds to roughly 1 millisecond.

[image: Zoomed in plot]

I am aware that that 1024 bytes can be transmitted per frame for an Isochronous Endpoint with USB 2.0 High Speed supporting a polling period or bInterval of 125 microseconds, with the USBAudio device able to transmit 1024 bytes per micro-frame, as opposed to the 1 millisecond bInterval for USB Full-Speed.

It appears that the USB host controller is only issuing Isochronous IN tokens, or polling, every 1 milliseconds instead of 125 microseconds. Hence the audio streaming interface on the RPi configured for the sampling frequency and the device's bInterval, has to wait for the subsequent audio data to arrive.

---

When I reprogram my SoC dev kit and configure it to be a USB Audio 2.0 device albeit with bInterval=4 (Thus support for polling period of 1 millisecond), there is no flaw in the transmitted sinusoidal signal with no blank/silent period after transmission of 1024 samples. This isn't surprising given the PyAduio stream configuration and Endpoint configuration, a frame of 1024 samples was expected after every millisecond by the audio application (PyAudio stream).

[image: Recorded Audio for bInterval=4, hence period=1 ms]

Zoomed in:
[image: Zoomed In - Recorded Audio for bInterval=4, hence period=1 ms]

---

**Is the inability of the USB controller to issue IN tokens every 125 microseconds:**

- A PyAudio problem i.e. it doesn't support requests to issue IN tokens
  for 125 microsecond microframes ?
- Related to latencies caused by other processes on the OS?
- Underlying issue with the ALSA HAL?
- A hardware issue? (The RPi 3 B+ ports and controller are USB 2.0 compliant though)

**Is there a way to ensure seamless audio streaming using PyAudio with 125 microseconds polling interval? Otherwise a polling interval of 1 millisecond for the endpoint will reduce the achievable throughput by a factor of 8.**

---

**Note:** I am **not** restricted to using the RPi as the USB host. If the community has successfully used PyAudio on other HW, to stream and record audio input via a USB endpoint configured for 125 microseconds interval, please let me know.

---

I have included the code snippet below. I believe only the configuration parameters for opening the stream are important.

```
import pyaudio
import wave

form_1 = pyaudio.paUInt8 # 8-bit resolution
chans = 1 # 1 channel
samp_rate = 48000 # 48kHz sampling rate
chunk = 4096 
record_secs = 1 # seconds to record
dev_index = 2 # device index found by p.get_device_info_by_index(ii)
wav_output_filename = 'sinad.wav' # name of .wav file

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio() # create pyaudio instantiation

# create pyaudio stream
stream = audio.open(format = form_1,rate = samp_rate,channels = chans, \
                    input_device_index = dev_index,input = True, \
                    frames_per_buffer=chunk)
print("recording")
frames = []

# loop through stream and append audio chunks to frame array
for ii in range(0,int((samp_rate/chunk)*record_secs)):
    data = stream.read(chunk)
    frames.append(data)

print("finished recording")

# stop the stream, close it, and terminate the pyaudio instantiation
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()

# save the audio frames as .wav file
wavefile = wave.open(wav_output_filename,'wb')
wavefile.setnchannels(chans)
wavefile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(form_1))
wavefile.setframerate(samp_rate)
wavefile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wavefile.close()
```